# how to keep a distributed software up to date on Linux machines

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, distributed-computing

I have my own distributed software running on few RasPi (20+) in different geographical locations, but every time i change something in my app, i have to update the excuteble in all Pi's manually, what are your suggestions to automate this process?

Comment: Take a look at [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/community/)